# Send image with formData to Laravel using AJAX (405 Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I would like to send an image with jquery ajax method to my server where laravel is installed but get a 405 Method not allowed error.

I also tried to create an "any" root, but still won't work.
Also with all other posts on this topic I couldn't solve my problem.

So here is my javascript code.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', resp);

$.ajax({
  url: '/images/store',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}
});
```

on the Server side i use the Resource controller of laravel so this is the snippet from my routing file.

```
Route::resource('images', 'ImageController');
```

I think the store method of laravel is a post route, but as mentioned above also with an any route I get the 405 error.

Comment: add mime type like `mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',` and try

Answer (score 0):

In fact, according to the laravel 5 doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers

If you want to use the store() method in your controller, you will just need to sent the request to "/images" (but not "/images/store") with the POST method